# java library to output bar/line graphs to PDF document

Tags: google-app-engine, pdf, graph

I am looking for a library that supports printing of bar/line graphs directly into PDF. The graphs need not be shown on screen, they can be directly output to the PDF document.

Comment: Which is it, RTF or PDF?

Comment: Is this on App Engine? What language?

Comment: Yes it is on App Engine- language is Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would iText + JFreeChart make it? One problem is that it is on GPL. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/02/generate-pie-chart-bar-graph-in-pdf-using-itext-jfreechart.html

Comment: I used LaTeX + JFreeChart (called through python) for a project a while back. It worked out well, and my results were nice, but I think you'd be better off keeping everything in Java like okrasz suggested.

Comment: And update - actually the JFreeChart itself claims to have export to PDF, so maybe even the iText is not needed. JFreeChart is on LGPL, so you can use in proprietary code. http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/

Comment: An update- I just checked, jfreechart cannot be used on App Engine because it requires some of the classes that are not on App Engine's Whitelist- however one possible solution is Google Charts API -this API takes the parameters for generating the graph as input and generates a graph in the form of PNG image- so I just have to generate the graph, then add that image into PDf. Another thing that I checked was that itext can be used in Google App Engine only if the pdf is pure text. Because if I want to add image to pdf with itext, again that uses classes not on App Engine's whitelist.

Comment: OK, one solution to this problem (of being able to use images in PDF file creation from Google App Engine Application) is to use PDFJET library- that has an OS edition that is compatible with Google App Engine. And there is a java library called jcharts that makes use of Google Charts API in Java very easy. Hence I plan to use jcharts+ pdfjet for graph generation in pdf.